# How to fill the siteminder "authentication required" chrome popup when running selenium ui tests

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, asp.net-mvc-5, siteminder

I have an intranet ASP.NET MVC5 application. It uses windows authentication at the moment.
We have Selenium UI smoke tests which overrides the credentials by making it a part of the url. 
`E.g http://username:pswd@localhost`

We are now thinking of using Siteminder to handle the authentication.
Web applications using Siteminder pops up a Authentication Required dialog (using Chrome browser), but the username and password text boxes do not have an 'id' that selenium can use to fill in the text.

How do I override the credentials in a web application that uses siteminder?

Answer (score 0):

Generally i will use AutoIT in java, to work with these authentication popups which are not recognized by webdriver and not avoided by passing credentials in URL it self.

So, you can use AutoIT here, in java we also user ROBOT class some times..

One more option is, when started URL is re-routed to another URL when authentication popups appears, then try, by using that re-routed URL with passing credentials.. i am not used it but thinking it may works..

Thank You,
Murali